# ¿Cómo agrego compatabilidad con IE9 a flex?

Tags: javascript, css, html5, css3

Quisiera saber si hay forma de añadirle compatibilidad a flex box con internet explorer 9

Comment: Para evitar los votos negativos edita la pregunta y muestra el avance que tengas a manera que puedas mostrar un [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución a tu problema sería esta alternativa no sé si la habrás contemplado https://github.com/jonathantneal/flexibility hace que sea compatible.

Comment: Gracias, esta interesante el aporte